# How to Calculate and Maintain Last Two Distinct Values of Rolling Max in Time series Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame that contains daily price data, and I'm trying to calculate a rolling maxover a 6-month period (using a window of 126 days). In addition to the rolling max, I want to create two additional columns:

**last_distinct_rolling_max**: This column should hold the previous distinct rolling max value until a new distinct value is encountered.

**second_last_distinct_rolling_max**: This column should hold the second last distinct value of the rolling max.
Here's an example of the data and the desired output:

| DateTime | Price | rolling_max | last_distinct_rolling_max | second_last_distinct_rolling_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-12-31 | 1468.36 | 1468.36 | NAN | NaN |
| 2008-01-02 | 1477.16 | 1477.16 | 1468.36 | NaN |
| 2008-01-03 | 1450 | 1477.16 | 1468.36 | NaN |
| 2008-01-04 | 1490 | 1490 | 1477.16 | 1468.36 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the duplicated data, [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
# ensuring datetime type and computing the rolling max
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['rolling_max'] = df.rolling('126D', on='DateTime')['Price'].max()

# function to shift the non repeated values
def next_distinct_max(s, *args):
    return (s.mask(s.eq(s.shift())).dropna().shift(*args)
             .reindex(s.index, method='ffill')
           )

# computing the last and second to last distinct max
df['last_distinct_rolling_max'] = next_distinct_max(df['rolling_max'], 1)

df['second_last_distinct_rolling_max'] = next_distinct_max(df['rolling_max'], 2)
```

*NB. `s.eq(s.shift())` can be replaced by `s.duplicated()` if a general de-duplication is desired.*

Output:

```
    DateTime    Price  rolling_max  last_distinct_rolling_max  second_last_distinct_rolling_max
0 2007-12-31  1468.36      1468.36                        NaN                               NaN
1 2008-01-02  1477.16      1477.16                    1468.36                               NaN
2 2008-01-03  1450.00      1477.16                    1468.36                               NaN
3 2008-01-04  1490.00      1490.00                    1477.16                           1468.36
```